# How to create workbook in Jmeter using JSR223 or beanshell sampler?

Tags: jmeter, apache-poi, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, apache-tika

I'm getting error when trying to create a workbook in the Jmeter.
I'm using "tika-app.jar"
After workbook creation is done I want to write data in excel xlx file.

Below is my JSR223 sampler:
[image: JSR223]

Error response which I'm getting is as below:

[image: view tree error]

Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy `tika-app-xxx.jar` to ["lib" folder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Switch to [`groovy` language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
4. Your code should start working without "Class not found" errors

If you're looking for "recipes" with regards to how to fill the Excel file check out [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Just in case a piece of code from the above guide:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
// Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);
// Or do it on one line.
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);
// Write the output to a file
try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
}
```

Comment: The Apache Tika App single jar is intended for standalone use, not to be added to the classpath of another Java program! Why not simply direct the OP to add the Apache POI jars and dependencies, since that's all they need?